# appendChild doesn't seem to be playing nice in FireFox

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn how to create a  as a child of another  using JavaScript.  My example below is functioning fine in Chrome and IE, but in Firefox I get an error that says "viewport is not defined" for the viewport.appendChild line in the JS.

The html looks like this:

```
<body>
<div id="viewport"></div>
</body>
```

and the JS looks like this:

```
function createDiv() {

    var divTag = document.createElement("div");

    divTag.className ="tile";

    viewport.appendChild(divTag);

}
```

Comment: Mozilla is a strict - you can`t ommit steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you haven't defined `viewport`. Somewhere in the function above the `appendChild` line, add this:

```
var viewport=document.getElementById('viewport');
```

Comment: I must add that in Internet Explorer every element with an ID is also a global variable. That's why the code "worked" there.